# getting image from firebase and inserting into SQLite and Displaying into Image View...

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-storage

I am Trying to Get a Picture from Firebase Storage from the DownloadURl inside my Firebase Database ..

Firebase Structure

**Users**

|**_9304809841**

```
    |__IMAGE :"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zumi- 
              60a8f.appspot.com/o/Profile_Image%2Fcropped-122662379.jpg?
             alt=media&token=c8f3e9ee-637d-4bdd-9a76-a186ecd07e37"
```

I am Using the Below Code To Get the Image from the URL ..

```
final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(URL);  //FETCHING THE URL FROM FIREBASE DATABASE..
            try {

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

                //check 200 OK for success
                final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error in HttpSTATUS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //return;

                }

                final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    try {
                        // getting contents from the stream
                        inputStream = entity.getContent();
                        //inputStream = (InputStream) new URL(params[0].toString()).getContent();

                        byte[] image = new byte[inputStream.available()];
                        inputStream.read(image);
                        values.put("image", image); //inserting the Values into ContentVAlues



                    } finally {
                        if (inputStream != null) {
                            inputStream.close();
                        }
                        entity.consumeContent();
                    }
                    if (values != null) {
                        Cdb.insert("current_Luser", null, values); // INSERTING INTO SQLite DB
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Entity is Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // You Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException
                getRequest.abort();
                Log.d("",e.toString());
               // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

I am Trying to Retrieve the Image using

```
Cursor c=Cdb.rawQuery("select email_phone,status,Dname,image from current_Luser",null);

        Toast.makeText(this, "No of record : "+c.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(c.moveToNext()) {

            if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                email.setText(c.getString(0).replace("@zumi.com", "").toString());
                name.setText(c.getString(2));
                status.setText(c.getString(1));
                byte[] img = c.getBlob(3);
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);
                showpotos.setImageBitmap(bmp);

             }
```

The Data is Inserted as [B@d0ca6a3 Value into SQLite DB..But It Does Not Show up in the Image View....

Pls Help..

Comment: if you just want to download the image try using `Glide` or `Picasso`. It will entirely replace the `HttpClient` with only one line of code.

Comment: Downloading and Storing to SQLite ....Both are Important

Comment: Glide and Picasso can also cache the file so you don't need to store in in SQLite, eliminating the problem. For other data you could use the Firebase Realtime Database, which uses SQLite under the hood for offline storage, but doesn't make you go through all the hassle of using it directly.

Comment: Why dont you use the built in image downloading API from firebase? https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files

Answer (score 0):

The use of `available(`) in this statement may be causing problems:

`byte[] image = new byte[inputStream.available()]`

The [documentation for available()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) says:

> Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the
>   total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never
>   correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer
>   intended to hold all data in this stream